# angular extract field of an array of object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I don't understand something and need explanations please !

I have a datatable and selection of lines generate in my .ts an array of Operation object. here is my object class :

```
export class Operation {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

this is the declaration of array :

```
selectedOperations: Operation[];
```

when I log in console before extraction of ids, I have this :

```
this.selectedOperations = {"selected":[{"id":1,"name":"My name 1"},{"id":3,"name":"My name 3"}]}
```

and when I want to extract ids with this :

```
let ids = this.selectedOperations.map(o => o.id);
```

I have an exception =>

```
this.selectedOperations.map is not a function
```

It's not the first time I have this problem and I'd like to understand why. I search some reasons and found differences between Array and object[] ? I think it's not really an array because there is the **{"selected":** before the array...

Can someone tell me the thing and help me for extract ids ?

thanks a lot !

Comment: selectedOperations is being set to an object. map() is a function of arrays in javascript, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

{"selected":[{"id":1,"name":"My name 1"},{"id":3,"name":"My name 3"}]} => this is of type object, whereas your array declaration looks like this selectedOperations: Operation[];

You either directly assign the array to your variable:

```
this.selectedOperations = [{"id":1,"name":"My name 1"},{"id":3,"name":"My name 3"}];
```

Or you can change your variable type to any or object:

```
selectedOperations: any;

this.selectedOperations = {"selected":[{"id":1,"name":"My name 1"},{"id":3,"name":"My name 3"}]}

const ids = this.selectedOperations.selected.map(o => o.id);
```

this.selectedOperations.map is not a function error is caused by the initialization, map function is reserved for arrays, therefore it throws an error when you try to use it on an object type variable.

I would recommend the first approach by the way, declaring a variable as any or object is contradicting with the purpose of Typescript.

Comment: oh thanks a lot for explanation ! It's ok now, I could think this !

Answer (score 0):

You need to make some improvements to the code. In order to get the `ids`, you need to add `selected` to  `this.selectedOperations`. See below.

```
let ids = this.selectedOperations.selected.map(o => o.id);
```